# Android studio - Bing Maps - Cannot resolve symbol 'microsoft'

Tags: android, bing-maps

[image: error msg]I am following the instructions from microsoft for the install of bing maps in Android app.
All appears to work well except the two lines

```
import com.microsoft.maps.MapRenderMode;
import com.microsoft.maps.MapView;
```

Both line are giving the same error - cannot resolve symbol microsoft.

Been through the code and all is as required.

Any one know why this is happening.

I have made sure all code as stated as per MS. Deleted and redid project and got exactly same error message.

Comment: Without knowing your error messages, probably related to [Issue #59: Could not parse POM...](https://github.com/microsoft/MapsSDK-Native/issues/59) which has a [comment of where to get the AAR](https://github.com/microsoft/MapsSDK-Native/issues/59#issuecomment-1385785120)

Comment: Please see error msg from Android Studio